# Core Data - Why does the object data stays fault even after accessing the property?

Tags: ios, core-data, kvc

I'm using Core Data and i have a managed object that the description states its data is fault.
I try to access a property with dot syntax but it's nil.
If I use *-[object valueForKey:@"key"];* the object fires fault and I get the correct value.
from then on i can access using *object.key* and it works.

Why does the object data stays fault even after accessing the property?

EDIT:
First I want to add that the property in question is of type NSDictionary and defined as Transformable in the model.

The code is simply:
`NSDictionary *d = object.property;` where object is a NSManagedObject that is managed by CoreData. After this line *d* is nil.

`NSDictionary *d = [object valueForKey:@"property"];`
After this line *d* is the correct value.

Comment: Can you give a code example? It's difficult to help you without one

Comment: I have created a simple Core Data project with a transformable NSDictionary attribute, and accessing the value with the property/dot syntax worked without problem. Did you include the generated .h file for the entity?

Comment: i created a subclass with .m and .h files. i did not know Core Data generates the .h files.

Comment: Select the Entity and choose "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass ..." from the menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had seen a similar issue a while ago. The model class had @synthesize for the properties instead of @dynamic.

Comment: I can't believe this ... I've been messing with some issue for 2 days now and this was the problem. So stupid :) Thanks man!